# I created a dropdown using<mat-select>with search option for list,When I clicks on space button in searchBox it is automatically selecting a list item

Tags: javascript, html, angular, mat-select, mat-option

Description : I created a dropdown list using  which contains list of items and one search field in the list. So that user can search the items in a list instead of scrolling through big list in drop down menu. And can select the items in the list.

Problem : When trying to search a list item in search box. If I want to give space in searchbox while searching. Instead of giving space in text box, it is automatically selecting an item in the select dropdown menu. So I`m unable to search for an item using spaces in search box.

Below is the code snippet.

```
<mat-select>
<input class="searchBox" placeholder=" Search Here" (input)="searchText($event);">
<mat-option *ngFor="let each of listItems" [value]="each.name">
{{each.name}}
<mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

When trying to search a list item in search box. If I want to give space in searchbox while searching. Instead of giving space in text box, it is automatically selecting an item in the select dropdown menu. So I`m unable to search for an item using spaces in search box.

My requirement is to give spaces also in search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got your problem here we can use `$event.stopPropagation()` function to stop selecting an item when giving space in the search column.

Here is the example with your code snippet.

```html
<mat-select>
<input class="searchBox" placeholder=" Search Here" (keyup)="searchText($event);" (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()">
<mat-option *ngFor="let each of listItems" [value]="each.name">
{{each.name}}
<mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

This line will solve your problem `<input class="searchBox" placeholder=" Search Here" (keyup)="searchText($event);" (keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()">`

**(keydown)="$event.stopPropagation()"** will disable the default feature you described.